flex-basis not displaying properly on iPad Safari
I have these two css:
.main-page-left{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 69%;
}

.main-page-right {
  flex-basis: 31%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

It works as expected on PC, but specifically on iPads using Safari, the flex-basis is ignored for some reason and content in main-page-right stretches to 100% width, either overflowing the main-page-right div, or stretching the div to be over 31% of the screen size.
For added context, main-page-right is filled with content boxes:
.main-page-right .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

Again, it works completely fine on PC browsers, but not specifically on iPads.
Added webkit stuff to the css, expecting that to fix the problem. Didn't work though.
    
.main-page-left {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 69%;
}
    
.main-page-right {
    flex-basis: 31%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}


Can you give a runnable snippet so it’s easy for us to try on an iPad? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
